# Unable to remove cookies from angularjs with params

Tags: angularjs, cookies

In AngularJs I have some issue with removing $cookies **ngCookies**. I'm setting cookies using subdomain i.e subdomain.example.com

Add cookie code:

```
$cookies.put('myCookie', true, {"path": "/", "domain":".example.com"});
```

Remove cookie code (which is not working)

```
$cookies.remove('myCookie', {"path": "/", "domain":".example.com"});
```

but if I remove params from cookies code then it will work fine

Add cookie code without params:

```
$cookies.put('myCookie1', true);
```

Remove cookie code without params

```
$cookies.remove('myCookie1');
```

Comment: Its better to use localStorage than Cookies

Comment: Add cookie with params works? Only remove doesn't - right?

Comment: yes remove is not removing the cookie

Answer (score 1):

```
$cookies.put('myCookie', true, {"path": "/", "domain":".example.com","expires":-1});
```

you may have a try

Comment: Not working, Cookie is still there. I want to remove that from browser cookies

Comment: then cookie expires value whether is -1 or not ?